# MVC, WCF ASP.NET 4.0 & JQUERY

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax, wcf, .net-4.0

I've spent the past few days getting frustrated with WCF, so I've decided to post for help on here because.. well.. I don't have a clue where to start!.. any help would be appreciated!

Firstly: When creating a WCF Service in .Net 4.0, which template should I use if I want to be able to create a service that will accept data from an AJAX POST using JQuery? (I'd like to be able to have a Global.asax if possible).

Secondly: My service works fine in the WCF Test Client, however when I manage to get it to accept GET requests, the Test Client stops showing the service methods. POST methods just seem to refuse to work outright.

I'd like to develop a WCF service that will run on an IIS server that I can hook into from any one of my applications via a JQuery Ajax call.

If anyone has a tutorial that point's me in the right direction, that would be greatly appreciated as I havn't been able to find anything on WCF using .Net 4, that works.

Cheers

Comment: Is there any reason in particular that you want to use WCF? If your service will only be consumed by jQuery requests you could just use a Controller in your MVC app. There are plenty of example on how to make this work with pure MVC without messing with WCF but perhaps you have other requirements that force you to use WCF (?)

Comment: Hello Hector, We did want to have a service hosted that a lot of our different apps could hook into, in different ways, not just JQuery. JQuery was just the method I was trying to get to work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first thing that you should consider is the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) restriction. If you are not able to comply with it and your web service is not hosted on the same domain as the consuming AJAX script you may stop reading my answer here and rethink your architecture.

If you are still reading you could start by defining the service contract and implementation as usual:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IFoo
{
    [OperationContract]
    string GetData(int value);
}

public class FooService : IFoo
{
    public string GetData(int value)
    {
        return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);
    }
}
```

Then you add a `fooservice.svc` file which will expose the service in IIS:

```
<%@ ServiceHost 
    Language="C#" 
    Debug="true" 
    Service="SomeNs.FooService" 
    CodeBehind="FooService.svc.cs" 
    Factory="System.ServiceModel.Activation.WebScriptServiceHostFactory"
%>
```

The last line `Factory="System.ServiceModel.Activation.WebScriptServiceHostFactory"` is extremely important as this is what will allow you to use JSON.

The last part is web.config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior>
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
            </behavior>
         </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
```

And finally an HTML page sending AJAX request to consume the service:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>WCF Test</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.json.org/json2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $.ajax({
                // Notice the URL here: Need to be hosted on the same domain
                url: '/fooservice.svc/getdata',
                type: 'post',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                data: JSON.stringify({ value: 7 }),
                success: function (result) {
                    alert(result.d);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Cheers mate, I wasn't aware of the same origin policy. Very useful information! Excellent answer! Thanks very much!